# On the fabricjs how can you determine if an object already exists at certain coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have been working with fabricjs for the last few weeks and I cannot find a solution for an issue I am having.
I have an object and I would like to programmatically determine if the area around it is "empty" (there are no objects ), so if I would add an object there they would not intersect.

I have been playing around with canvas.findTarget and different "virtual" objects but I cannot get anything to work.

This is a solution I found:

```
var targetPoint = new fabric.Point(target.left + offset + 1, target.top + 1);
          if (obj.containsPoint(targetPoint)) {
            objectOnRight = obj;
          }
```

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you fairly close (some code I've used, in the past, to display a context menu):

```
fabric.util.addListener(document.getElementsByClassName('upper-canvas')[0], 'contextmenu', function (env) {
    var x = env.offsetX;
    var y = env.offsetY;
    var itemIndex = -1;
    $.each(canvas.getObjects(), function (i, e) {
        // e.left and e.top are the middle of the object use some "math" to find the outer edges
        if (e.selectable && e.id != 'canvasNumbers') {
            var d = e.width * e.scaleX / 2;
            var h = e.height * e.scaleY / 2;
            if (x >= (e.left - d) && x <= (e.left + d)) {
                if (y >= (e.top - h) && y <= (e.top + h)) {
                    itemIndex = i;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (itemIndex > -1) {
        canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.getObjects()[itemIndex]);
        canvasSelectedItem = canvas.getObjects()[itemIndex];
        $('.contextmenu').css({
            top: env.pageY + 'px',
            left: env.pageX + 'px'
        }).show();
    }
    env.preventDefault();
    return false; //stops the event propigation
});
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.  Happy to help more!

Comment: Hi Tim and thank you for the reply. If I understood correctly this code displays a contextual menu without overlapping with existing elements? I am trying a similar approach with iterating over canvas objects, I will get back to you if I have a solution based on what I saw in your code. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct, and no worries. Please do get back to me once you've 'digested' :-) the code.  I can hopefully help further.

Comment: Hi, Tim! I found a solution based on what you presented. I create a point relative to the object I am adding and just check if any of the canvas objects contains that point. I added an example code to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea of using two events here to catch when mouse is over a given object and when out:

```
 myobject[i].on('mouseover', () => {
    console.log("mouse over"+i)

 });
 myobject[i].on('mouseout', () => {
    console.log("mouse out"+i)

 });
```